# Apply code to active document not document opened with Documents.Add

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-template

I got a VBA project from colleague who is retired.

I have to change a function:

```
Documents.Add Template:= _
    "c:\word\Link.dot", _
    NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0
```

Here a new document (another Word file) is created with a template.

This template also relates data from another project "Common".

Basically, `Documents.Add Template:= _"c:\word\Link.dot"`
in Link.dot the `Document_Open()` is executed and the Common project is initialized.

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
    Common.Initialize
End Sub
```

I don't want a second document opened by `Documents.add`, it should use the already active document.

I tried these two variants:

#1

```
Dim oDoc As Document
Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
oDoc.AttachedTemplate = "c:\word\Link.dot"
```

#2

```
ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate = "c:\word\Link.dot"
```

Nothing happens to both of them, even no Runtime Error. I think it's because Document_Open() wasn't executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Document_Open()` responds to the Open event. As you are not opening a document when attaching the template it will not execute.

You can execute the code directly though.

```
ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate = "c:\word\Link.dot"
Common.Initialize
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got a "Runtime error 4198" @ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate = "c:\word\Link.dot", the link cannot be wrong, the File Link.dot is under this Path.

Comment: The code is correct so either 1) you don't have any documents open; or 2) the path is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, sorry. It was my mistake. ^^, you helped me a lot, thank you very much.